# Only show parent if child contains certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of divs that appear on multiple pages, that have this pattern:

```
<div class=“entry”>
  <div id=“post”>
    <div class=“text”>
      <div class=“service”></div>
      <div class=“timeline”>
        <div class=“entry-title”>
          #hashtagOne
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=“entry”>
  <div id=“post”>
    <div class=“text”>
      <div class=“service”></div>
      <div class=“timeline”>
        <div class=“entry-title”>
          #hashtagTwo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=“entry”>
  <div id=“post”>
    <div class=“text”>
      <div class=“service”></div>
      <div class=“timeline”>
        <div class=“entry-title”>
          #hashtagThree
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This group appears on multiple pages.

My ideal javascript/jquery solution is something like this:

1. display:none on all div class="entry"
2. if child div class="entry-title" contains #something, change parent div class="entry" to display:block

so that on Page One I can insert this code to only show #hashtagOne, on Page Two only #hashtagTwo, etc. etc.

Comment: check this demo if this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what's with those quotes lol :))

Comment: hey @guradio there's no fiddle attached to that. thanks for the help!

Comment: May be this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/5L4Lvaen/

Comment: @RayonDabre i think you have to do something like `^#` since he wants to have **contains #something**

Comment: @guradio, I did not get you..

Comment: @RayonDabre i think you want to c heck the first character of the div if it starts with `#` then show or hide :)

Comment: maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/5L4Lvaen/3/ @Jony

Comment: @guradio, There is no ready-made(short) approach for this I guess..Your fiddle looks fine..

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, just use :contains() and .closest() together either on page load or whatever event you want this display:block behavior to run.

As you want to show based on differnt pages, I suggest to use page title and set it to title="Page One" and title="Page Two" etc and then compare it in document ready state and show accordingly the desired div

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('div.entry').hide();
   if(jQuery(document).find("title").text() == 'Page One')
   {
       jQuery( "div.entry-title:contains('#something')" ).closest('.entry').show();
    }
    else if(jQuery(document).find("title").text() == 'Page Two')
    {
       jQuery( "div.entry-title:contains('#something Else')" ).closest('.entry').show();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.entry-title').each(function(i,v){
if ($(this).text().trim().charAt(0) =="#") {
  $(this).closest('.entry').show();
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ybstx9o/

Answer (score 0):

This simply works fine :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".entry").each(function(){
        if($(this).find(".entry-title:contains('#something')").length > 0){
            $(this).css("display","block");
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".entry").find(".entry-title").text(function(key, text) {
            if (text.indexOf("#")>=0) {
                $(this).parents(".entry").hide()
            }
        })
```

Here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kJT9Zu10Gb5VhKpiiRyE?p=preview)